# Using a single Servlet for multiple HTML forms

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I am new to Java's JSP and Servlets.

I am trying to control two different HTML forms with single Servlet Controller. The approach that I am following, is creating a hidden field in both forms, then, in my Servlet I've written:

```
String extra= request.getParameter("value"); 
//value is name of hidden textbox in my both forms
```

then, using `if-else`

```
if(extra.equals(x))
  do this....
else if(extra.equals(y))
  do this...
```

My question is, Is there any better approach to solve this problem? My implementation is very tedious, and I want to use single servlet in my whole application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up-to you to how to handle different forms. Since a Servlet can only have one "doPost"" method, the approach you're using will do the trick, but, I would rather consider introducing a framework such as Spring MVC which will save you several lines of code, and will allow you to use a Servlet (Controller in MVC pattern) per multiple forms.

A best practice I have always followed, is to have a servlet/controller per page, if your forms are embedded in different pages, I think you can consider having two servlets instead of one.

Comment: That means having as many as servlets wouldn't cost the application?

Comment: If you use a framework, Spring MVC for example, you would only have to use one servlet, regardless of how many actions or requests you have on your forma/page.

Answer (score 1):

It's doable, but I wouldn't do that thinking about scalability.
Do you have any restriction to use exactly one servlet?
If you plan to develop something bigger, you might try a few frameworks, like [JSF](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/) or have you project started with [Springboot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).
You also might try using web services to interact with your application. In this case, Jackson + Jersey work nice together ([example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/)).

Comment: You are Right. But as i mentioned i am totally new to Java Web and practicing from basics. And I presume using new servlet on every new request is not a good practice.

Comment: A servlet is not created for each request. You might want to read about a [servlet life cycle](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-life-cycle.htm). It's actually very common having a servlet per form.

Answer (score 1):

If you are requesting same method(GET, POST, etc) for both the `forms` and you have common task for both `JSPs`, you can create single `Servlet`, just like you did.

But If it is not limited to one or two field then code will become complex, less readable and hard to maintain. So, In that case I would recommend you to make the separate `Servlet` for individual form.

Answer (score 1):

Good solution, but I recommend specifying dedicated path for each form where all the paths are for one servlet.

the servlet path would be like `{"/path","/path/*"}` and form one would call the `/path/cgi0`, `/path/cgi1`, ...

Then simply check the requested path instead of a parameter.

This will keep the busy business and code at the server side, but gives better and more API like system to clients(if they care)

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is including a doGet and a doPost response from the same servlet, then with your action x, send a Get response to the Post part of your servlet